# How to display an exception message from stored procedure in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I have an application with Crystal Report, which uses stored procedure from Oracle(I am using Oracle 10g Express Edition). As of now, when an exception is thrown from the stored procedure, say 'division by zero' exception, the message is displayed in an alert box in CR. I want to display it within the report, instead of the data. Is there any way to do it?

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Division by zero exception');
```

This is how I am throwing exception from the stored procedure. Then I have bound the stored procedure with Data Expert. I use REF CURSOR to return value from the stored procedure to Crystal Report.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Crystal Reports are there any way to catch SQL Exceptions? If so you could get the SQL Error Code and based on the error code you can display the message you would want to.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports are there any way to catch SQL Exceptions? If so you could get the SQL Error Code and based on the error code you can display the message you would want to.

If not, try the following approach, i.e. to return error code and error message when exception is raised.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getemployees (
    p_no                  IN        employees.emp_number%TYPE,
    rcursor               OUT sys_refcursor,
    return_message    OUT VARCHAR2,
    return_code           OUT NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN rcursor FOR
        SELECT  *
          FROM  employees
         WHERE  emp_number = p_no;

    return_message := NULL;
    return_code := 0;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE
    THEN
        return_message := SQLERRM;
        return_code := SQLCODE;
END getemployees;
/
```